# How can I pass an R expression in R Markdown YAML to CSS parameter?

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown

Here is the problem:

I developed a tool with R Markdown that process and generate some company monthly report.

I've been trying to automate the location of a CSS file that styles this report by using this code:

```
---
title: "Gerador de Relatórios VANT"

author: 'Empresa: International Paper Brasil'

date: 'Equipe: P&D'

output:

  html_document:

    css: !expr paste(dirname(dirname(rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$path)), 'CSS/vant_style.css', sep = '/')
---
```

I don't know for sure, but I think maybe I cannot use use the function `rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$path` because when knitting the document, it runs in another session.

I want to do so because I have to share with my boss and with some colleagues and I don't want they need to change anything here, in css file.

Is there anyway to do what I need?

PS: I'm doing this way because I have so many folders in my project which is not only the tool folder but a lot more data and annotations, I understand it would be easier to leave everything in only one folder.

Comment: I think you can render R code in the YAML like in the body of the document. `css: \`r paste(...)\``

Comment: @dcruvolo I don't think so. I've already tried this way. The way I put in the code works if I don't use the function `rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$path` beacuase I think the session doesn't run under Rstudio API, or something like that. I've figured out another way to do what I want: I'm using the `dirname()` in association with `getwd()` function (which returns the path of the current RMD file). Now I don't have to worry anymore on describing to everyone I share my project how to change the sources folders to run the tool. Thanks for trying to help! =)